# fgets() is not being executed

Tags: c, fopen

I've been trying to write a program that lets a user open a .txt file in read, write or append mode and then edit its contents.

So far when I run the program, it's capable of opening a file in any selected mode, however the bit of code in the last if-statement doesn't seem to get executed. I've tried a few things and haven't been able to get it working. The fopen() function seems to work correctly, but the bit of code after it is not being run.

Is anyone able to tell me why it's not being executed?

I'm still quite new to coding and C, so I suspect that there may be something I'm not understanding either about the language or computer systems. I appologise in advance for not noticing any obvious mistakes in my code and logic.
I'm grateful for all help and it would be seriously appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "bsp10048.h"
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_EINGABE 80


/*----- Dateiöffner und Editor -----*/


int main(void)
{
    FILE* file_ptr;
    char str[200], selection[2], mode[2], name[200];
    int repeat = 1; 

    printf("\nPlease enter filename: ");
    fgets(name, 200, stdin);

    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;

    strcat(name, ".txt");

    printf("\n''r'' = Read-mode (Open file for reading)");
    printf("\n''w'' = Write-mode (Create file for writing)");
    printf("\n''a'' = Append-mode (Open file for appending)");
    
    /*MODE SELECTION*/
    while (repeat) {
        printf("\n\nBitte Modus waehlen: ");
        fgets(selection, 2, stdin);
        
        switch (selection[0]) {

        case 'r':
            /*Lesemodus*/
            strcpy(mode, "r");
                printf("\nRead-mode selected\n");
            repeat = 0;
            break;
        
        case 'w':
            /*Schreibemodus*/
            strcpy(mode, "w");
                printf("\nWrite-mode selected\n");
            repeat = 0;
            break;
        
        case 'a':
            /*Appelliermodus*/
            strcpy(mode, "a");
                printf("\nAppend-mode selected\n");
            repeat = 0;
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nInvalid mode!");
            break;
        }
    }

    
    
    if ((file_ptr = fopen(name, mode)) != NULL) {
        printf("File successfully opened!");
    }

    if (mode != "r") {
        fgets(str, 200, stdin);
        while (str[0] != '\n') {
                fprintf(str, 200, file_ptr);
                fgets(str, 200, stdin);
            }
    }

    fclose(file_ptr);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Fix the compiler warnings first. They are more like errors.

Comment: `if (mode != "r")` This is not how you compare a string. Use `strcmp`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: `if ((file_ptr = fopen(name, mode)) != NULL)`: what happens if `file_ptr` is `NULL`?

Comment: @Gerhardh: That said, it's unconditionally true as written (stack array address will never equal the string literal storage address), so the code in that block would *always* run (including when it makes no sense, but at least it would run when it *does* make sense too). The code is broken, but it's not responsible for the code in that block appearing not to run (that would presumably be the `fprintf(str, 200, file_ptr);`, which I'm guessing was intended to be an `fwrite`?).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I know. I did not post as an answer because that is only one of the problems in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code.

1. Comparing strings:

```c
if (mode != "r")
```

You cannot compare a string by comparing with a string literal. This will compare addresses and very likely never be same.

That condition will always be true as both strings cannot have same address.

You might revisit your learning material and check how strings are handled correctly.

Use `strcmp` instead:

```c
if (strcmp(mode,"r") != 0)
```

2. Writing your output:

```c
fprintf(str, 200, file_ptr);
```

As ShadowRanger already mentioned in comments, this is wrong. You should get a few warnings about that line. You messed up `fprintf` parameters with `fwrite`.

Use this instead:

```c
fprintf(file_ptr,"%s\n", str);
```

3. Use a debugger to watch what your program does.

You claim that the `fgets` in that `if` part is never executed. That is actually not true.

You have this line in your code:

```c
fgets(selection, 2, stdin);
```

That will read only 1 byte from `stdin` and use second byte for terminating 0 byte.
Any other character, including `\n` is left in the buffer.

If you then come here:

```c
        fgets(str, 200, stdin);
        while (str[0] != '\n') {
```

You will read only a single `\n` into `str` and your `while` condition will immediately be `false`.

You should provide enough space to consume your `\n` in the `fgets` call above.

On a sidenote:
If that condition wasn't `false` already on first iteration, you would probable face a segmentation fault due to passing invalid parameters to `fprintf` as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate and informative answer! It's seriously, SERIOUSLY appreciated and I'm really thankful that you helped me out so much. In fact, through your answer I gained a more thorough understanding of C and its functions. THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: In addition, I will heed your advice and go over the section covering strings my learning material again (and then potentially again and again). It has been around a month since I have covered it for the first time. 
The book I'm learning from is actually excellent, but I'm just a bit of a slow (though thorough over time) learner. I again want to say that I really appreciate your help and that I'm thankful.

Comment: *The book I'm learning from is actually excellent* The main problem with that claim is that as a beginner you might not be able to detect that. A book might be good at explaining things but at the same time provide completely wrong advice.

Comment: You make a fantastic point. The book I've been learning from is actually from 1999-2000. It teaches to use functions like gets() which as I've recently learned are deprecated. 
Do you have a recommendation for a good book/resource to learn from?

Comment: When I learned C, C99 wasn't actually available and when it was released, tools for embedded targets weren't supporting it for quite a while. That means I don't have an overview of what's out there nowadays. But from other question I remember that "Modern C" is suggested frequently.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing, I have added "Modern C" to my reading list. 
I also want to once again express my appreciation for your help as I was able to get the program to function exactly as intended. Your answer really helped me in gaining a better understanding of the language.